# gSOAP: How to use SOAP instead of POST for specific service/schema

Tags: soap, gsoap

First off, let me apologize, because I don't know much about SOAP and most of what I'm saying is probably nonsense.

I upgraded some client-side code that was generated using gSoap 2.8.4 to gSoap 2.8.93

As far as I can tell, the program only sends one request to the server. Previously this request was wrapped in

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="bmf.gv.at:pkt/PKTSoap" xmlns:ns1="bmf.gv.at:pkt" xmlns:ns3="bmf.gv.at:pkt/PKTSoap12">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 ...
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

However with the code generated by the new version this envelope is missing. I understand that this is because the request is generated as a REST request instead of a SOAP one. I've found threads that talk about the //gsoap directive for the service setting the method-protocol to SOAP instead of POST, but I can only find these directives for requests to the sub-services /PKTSoap and /PKTSoap12, not to the root service bmf.gv.at:pkt, to which the request is sent. In fact that is not even called a service in the code, it's called a schema. And the requests to it are called top-level root elements of the schema. They are all automatically generated as REST requests.

**My question is how can I instruct gSoap to generate all requests as SOAP1.1 requests? Any help whatsoever is greatly appreciated.**

WSDL: https://pastebin.com/bmC8Hx6M

typemap.dat is the default one with the following appended:

```
ns1 = "bmf.gv.at:pkt"
ns2 = "bmf.gv.at:pkt/PKTSoap"
ns3 = "bmf.gv.at:pkt/PKTSoap12"
```

And I use the following commands to generate:

```
wsdl2h.exe -c -g -N ns %1.wsdl
soapcpp2.exe -c -C -I./import -1 %1.h
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question which request messages do not include the envelope.

Here is a quick way to test the generated source code, to verify that the SOAP1.1 envelope and body are included (I've used C++ here):

```
wsdl2h -L -g -N ns service.wsdl
soapcpp2 -1 -C -I import service.h
```

A small demo client, to test the request message:

```
#include "soapH.h"
#include "PKTSoap.nsmap"

int main()
{
  struct soap *soap = soap_new1(SOAP_XML_INDENT);
  _ns1__DatenpoolkontoErzeugen req;
  _ns1__Verarbeitung res;
  req.soap_default(soap);
  soap_call___ns2__PKTDatenpoolkontoErzeugen(soap, "http://", NULL, &req, res);
}
```

Compiled with:

```
c++ -o service service.cpp soapC.cpp soapClient.cpp stdsoap2.cpp
```

Then run:

```
$ ./service
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 526
Connection: close
SOAPAction: "bmf.gv.at:pkt/PKTDatenpoolkontoErzeugen"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="bmf.gv.at:pkt/PKTSoap" xmlns:ns1="bmf.gv.at:pkt" xmlns:ns3="bmf.gv.at:pkt/PKTSoap12">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:DatenpoolkontoErzeugen>
            <ns1:Absender xsi:nil="true"/>
        </ns1:DatenpoolkontoErzeugen>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This shows that `bmf.gv.at:pkt` requests are sent exactly as specified in the WSDL.